# How can I update workbook links when using pd.read_excel()?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The question is pretty simple, actually.
I'm reading an Excel file using Pandas. When I open it using Office's Excel in my Desktop I'm prompted to Enable Content and then Update Links [that is, update values in those cells importing information from cells in other workbooks and xslx files], so it reads other files in some other folders.
While using pd.read_excel('filename') however that option is not available, and I'm afraid it's importing the data previously contained in the spreadsheet without updating it. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm almost certain you can't do this directly using pd.read_excel, which relies on xlrd to read the excel file's contents and is not exposed to the events which trigger those "updating" (and other alerts) via COM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893870/refresh-excel-external-data-with-python