# Not able to save updated version of Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.6, excel-2016

I have an Excel sheet which has a data connection with PowerQuery. Usually, I used to click "Refresh All" to update the data. I want to automate this and wrote a Python script to do that.

However, in Excel I found under Connection Properties an option: "Refresh while opening". Now when I open the sheet, the Refresh automatically triggers and data is updated.

From Python code, I open this sheet and have put a sleep command so that it waits for 30 seconds till the sheet automatically refreshes. After that I am calling "Save As" to save the updated sheet with a different name.

I am using below code:

```
import win32com.client
import time

# Start an instance of Excel
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

# Open the workbook in said instance of Excel
wb = xlapp.workbooks.open("test.xlsx")

# Optional, e.g. if you want to debug
# xlapp.Visible = True

time.sleep(30)
wb.SaveAs("New.xlsx")

# Quit
xlapp.Quit()
```

I noticed, that even after "Save As", the data values are not updated. If I directly open Excel, without Python script, the Refresh works and then I manually click Save. It updates. But with above code, it is not saving the updated version.

Please advise.

Comment: Which data connection does the excel sheet have?

Comment: Power Query which connects to a SAP database. It works fine when I open sheet directly and I manually save. From python, I am not able to save the updated sheet.

Comment: probably the problem is then, that python does not really open the file, maybe you could execute the python code, while opening your folder with the excel and also make ~$ files visible, if this file does not pop-up for 30 seconds you now that it was not 'opened'

Comment: It opens. I tried "visible = true" and the refresh starts.

Comment: so it works now?

Comment: No even after adding "Refresh All" in Python, it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this, I think in your above coce the `wb.RefreshAll()`command is missing: [Refresh Excel External Data with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893870/refresh-excel-external-data-with-python)

```
import win32com.client
import time 
# Start an instance of Excel
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

# Open the workbook in said instance of Excel
wb = xlapp.workbooks.open("test.xlsx")

# Optional, e.g. if you want to debug
# xlapp.Visible = True

# Refresh all data connections.
wb.RefreshAll()
time.sleep(30)
wb.Save()

# Quit
xlapp.Quit()
```

Comment: In the code I provided in question, I have enabled Auto-Refresh as the sheet opens hence not used "Refresh All".