# How to refresh excel external data on mac?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My data is updating every few seconds on excel and I want to auto save it I can access it through python.

I saw this [Refresh Excel External Data with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893870/refresh-excel-external-data-with-python) but it's for windows, is there a similar thing I could use for mac?

Comment: Can you please share if you found any solution?