# Pandas read_excel - returning nan for cells having formula

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file that contains accounting data and also the file use formula for some of the cells. When I use pandas read_excel to read the values in the file, it returns `nan` value for cells having formula's. I have also used openpyxl, but still having the same issue.

Is there any way to read values instead of formula for cells having formula.

I have also attached the xlsx file used.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aOTYwtKTrqyjF16vDizzzvMkUsvdgRe1/view?usp=sharing

Thanks...

Comment: pandas and openpyxl do not implement excel formulas. This does:
https://formulas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/doc.html
Maybe that's what you are looking for?

Comment: The file link is broken.

Comment: @uttejh Updated File link

Answer (score 6):

i was facing the exact same issue as you when reading an excel file that has been appended to using excel writer. It happens because the links on the excel file is not updated hence the formulas do not calculate the value.

2 solutions that worked for me:

1. Open the file and update links when prompted OR
2. Add in code to refresh the file before reading it according to solution posted here. [Refresh Excel External Data with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893870/refresh-excel-external-data-with-python)

Hope this helps.

Edit: New user here, no idea how reject/approve works, any constructive feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Refreshing excel helped!

Answer (score 3):

Before working with your excelsheet make sure you have set the permissions of your excel file to read and write,if it is a read only file,then change to read-write.

```
import pandas as pd
your_data = pd.read_excel('yourfile.xlsx',sheet_name='your_sheet_name')
print(your_data) #checking
your_data.dropna(inplace=True)
your_data.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 1':'Total'},inplace =True) 
print(your_data['Total'].tolist()) #The column name where your formula is being calculated.
```

Comment: Still the same issue. Please check with the above sample file

Comment: The Total column seems to be empty??

Comment: Download the file and open in any excel viewer you can see the value ( it is hidden in google sheet preview )

Comment: @MuthuKumar you must select the B column in excel, right click and format cells. There in the Number section- by default it must be "General" change it to "12345.76" type of number. and save your excel sheet. The code above works fine.

Comment: Yes That is working, But I'm not supposed to do that

Comment: You can convert your dataframe to a csv file,that way you wont need to resave your excel file. Please consider approving the answer if it is working.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment so I have to put this in as an answer which it is not.

With your sample file I don't have any issues. I'm using python 3.8 and Pandas 0.25.3. Pandas reads it fine and the numbers are available. That said, my experience with reading values computed by formulas is that it depends on the complexity of the formula. Volatile functions like Index, Match will be read as nan, but more simple functions can be read in as numbers.

This is a workaround only and not a real solution, but if you can make a new column with a formula that just references the column with the complex formulas, then that column's data can be read.