# Pandas reading excel formula cells as NaN instead of the value the formulas return

Tags: python, pandas, excel-formula, nan

I have an excel template sheet that has some formulas in it. I use pandas to populate some of the columns in that sheet and then the formulas use that information to return a numerical value. Once I am done I save down the file.

When I try to copy that sheet with the formulas and use the information from it using pandas, all the cells where I have formals come back as NaN. If I manually open the excel file, press Save, and close out of it, then pandas reads the cells with the formulas as the numerical values, which is exactly what I want.

How can I get around the opening, saving, and closing the excel file manually every time, and have pandas be able to immediately read the numerical values from the formula cells instead of reading them as NaN?

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you show your code, please?

Comment: @JerzyPawlikowski I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893870/refresh-excel-external-data-with-python). It looks like I need to refresh the excel before I can use the formula data.

Comment: What libraries are you using ? xlwings ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.