# Refresh all Errors Excel Query with python

Tags: python, excel, powerquery, win32com

I was looking for a solution on how to refresh excel queries from python. I found [Refresh Excel External Data with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893870/refresh-excel-external-data-with-python) this super answer. However now I face an issue that sometimes my query cant refresh due to unavailability of a DB. So I need to catch this issue in my python script. Any ideas on how to do this?