# Is there a way to refresh Excel file using python or power automation

Tags: python, excel, power-automate

How to refresh Excel file using Power Automation or Python?

Comment: Power Automate - no. Python - yes: [Refresh Excel External Data with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893870/refresh-excel-external-data-with-python), [Python Script to Automate Refreshing an Excel Spreadsheet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-script-to-automate-refreshing-an-excel-spreadsheet/)

Comment: Refresh data tables/connections you mean?

Comment: Why would an Excel file need to be refreshed? What is causing it to change but not refresh?