# Auto updating excel file through Julia

Tags: excel, julia

I have an excel file that contains external data which it got through connecting with an API through a power query. Every day there is new data added to this external dataset. I want to write a script in Julia, which automatically updates this excel file such that it contains the latest data. How would I go about this/is this possible?

Comment: this will require an instance of excel to be executed in some way. for python, I've seen such packages. you might be able to do this with powershell or other microsoft-sanctioned scripting/automation

Comment: Basically for scenarios like this you need to have Excel installed (this cannot be done via open source excel compatibility implementation such as XLSX.jl). One such approach (that is loading in fact excel) is via Win COM. See this Python code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893870/refresh-excel-external-data-with-python   This library can be loaded via PyCall or PythonCall from Julia. If this is what you need and you have problem loading it via PyCall/PythonCall let me know